# Замена .swf файлов по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Есть 2 кнопки. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на них в определенной точке менялись *.swf* файлы.

Каждой кнопке соответствует определенный *.swf* файл.
Т.е. нажал одну, показывает один файл, нажал другую, на его месте появился второй.

CSS:

```
.btn1 {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
}
.btn1:hover { }
.btn2 {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #cco;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
}
.btn2:hover { }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button class="btn1"></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn2"></button>
</div>
<div align="center" style="width:640px;background-color:#ddd; margin:auto;margin-top:5%; border: solid 1px black; height: 340px; }">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <embed src="start.bmp" width="320" height="340"></embed>
    </div>
```

Вместо *"start.bmp"* должны появляться *.swf*, находящиеся в той же папке, что и HTML файл.

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы заменить `src` у `embed` при нажатии на кнопки `.btn1` и `.btn2`, можно:

- Добавить обработчики события `click` кнопкам после полной загрузки документа.
- Внутри обработчика поменять `src` у `embed` на заданное значение.

Код:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomReady);

function onDomReady() {
    var button1 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn1')[0];
    var button2 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn2')[0];
    var embed = document.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0];
    
    button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
        embed.src = "first.swf";
    });        
    button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        embed.src = "second.swf";
    }); 
};
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="btn1">first</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn2">second</button>
</div>
<div align="center" style="width:640px;background-color:#ddd; margin:auto;margin-top:5%; border: solid 1px black; height: 340px; }">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <embed src="start.bmp" width="320" height="340"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Какие минимальные доработки я бы провёл:

- Сделал бы кнопкам единый класс для единой обработки их нажатия. Ссылку на связанный *.swf* файл добавил бы в качестве атрибута. Например, атрибут `data-src`.
- Стили у `div`'ов, в которые обёрнут `embed`, вынес бы в CSS файл.
- Добавил бы `embed` ID для того, чтобы "не промахнуться" при выборе нужного `embed`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomReady);

function onDomReady() {
    var shownObject = document.getElementById('shownObject');
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    var buttonClickHandler = function() {
        shownObject.src = this.getAttribute('data-src');
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler);
    }
};
```

```css
.objectContainer {
    width: 640px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 340px;
}

.objectFloat {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="btn" data-src="first.swf">first</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn" data-src="second.swf">second</button>
</div>
<div align="center" class="objectContainer">
    <div class="objectFloat">
        <embed id="shownObject" src="start.bmp" width="320" height="340"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

И то же самое с jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var shownObject = $('#shownObject')[0];
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        shownObject.src = $(this).data('src');
    });
});
```

```css
.objectContainer {
    width: 640px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 340px;
}

.objectFloat {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="btn" data-src="first.swf">first</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn" data-src="second.swf">second</button>
</div>
<div align="center" class="objectContainer">
    <div class="objectFloat">
        <embed id="shownObject" src="start.bmp" width="320" height="340"/>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А как убрать надписи с кнопок "first" и "second"
В моем случае, там должны быть картинки.

Comment: @user184949 уберите текст _first_ и _second_ из HTML-кода кнопок и всё.